# Android- Secure client server communication

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I am very new to writing apps so please bear with me :)

I am writing an Android app that communicates with my server to send GET request and get some data from the server and show it to client (android app user).

**API URL**:
http://myserver.com/get.php

**GET data/variables**

1. **api**: my api key
2. extra GET variables

It'd be like:
http://myserver.com/get.php?api=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&extra=something&fields=here

So can an attacker see the API key by decoding the app with tools like apktool, smali etc? If yes  then how can I secure it?

Answer (score 0):

Note : the answer you are going to read are based on my experience and my research, feel free to comment if my information is wrong. Im not a network architect, but i have some experiences building `web services`, and did hours of research (because just like you, i dont understand about security at first). I hope this will help you.

1. Use `POST`, its safer than `GET` if you use `REST`.
2. Use `HTTPS` (i know its a little bit more expensive)
3. Use `SOAP`, instead of `REST` if you really need good security (ex : Banking Apps).
4. Use `Dexguard`/`Proguard` so your apps will be hard to reverse engineered.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I need to get some info from the server & show it to the client so I have to use GET. And I dont think its impossible to do reverse engg. even if I use Dexguard. Is there any secure way?